# I want to put Latlng value In Google Maps from Firebase, but I am getting errors

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I want this to be resolved kindly help me to resolve this issue.
I am using Resburrpi-3 for the location data longitude and latitude are uploading on firebase and now i want to retrieve longitude and latitude using firebase on google maps on latlong reference.

```
private DatabaseReference mReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = mReference.child("Tezgam");
    usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                latitude = snapm.child("lat").getValue(Long.class);
                longitude = snapm.child("long").getValue(Long.class);
                Speed = snapm.child("speed").getValue(String.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value

        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Tezgam\n Current location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}`
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Do you get any error message and can share the stack trace? Is the code running but not working as expected? Did you debug through it step by step?

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onMapReady()` method is probably being fired before the data is available in the `onDataChanged()` method. I am assuming the error you are getting is something like "latitude"  and "longitude"  are null (assumption, because the op did not show how the variables were declared). This is a race condition--One method is finished before the other method can provide data. You must accommodate for the missing data.

So change your `onMapReady()` code like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    updateMapLocation();
}
```

and change your snapshot code to:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
    // whenever data at this location is updated.

    for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        latitude = snapm.child("lat").getValue(Long.class);
        longitude = snapm.child("long").getValue(Long.class);
        Speed = snapm.child("speed").getValue(String.class);

    updateMapLocation();
    }
}
```

Now, add the `updateMapLocation()` method which will check if the latitude and longitude values are null else display the location:

```
private void updateMapLocation(){
    if(latitude == null || longitude == null){
        Log.e("updateMapLocation", "latitude or longitude is null")
    }
    else{
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Tezgam\n Current location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```